# Can't get Express @types working

Tags: express, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get the Express @types working but without any success. I'm using Visual Studio Code and I'd really love to have the autocompletition working. So far I've seen that installing the @types it gives the autocompletition too.

**Things that I've done:**
Installed express with npm: `npm i -g express`
Installed express-generator with npm: `npm i -g express-generator`
Generated the project with express-generator
cd into the project
Ran `npm i`
Installed types with npm: `npm i --save-dev @types/express`

    // Top of the file:
    var express = require('express');

```
app.use(function (req, res: Express.Response, next) {
    var err: any = new Error('Not Found');

    //if I try to use res.end() it gets underlined in red
    res.end('some text');
});
```

As you can see the `Express.Response` was suggested by vscode, so this kinda confuses me. How can you find the Express.Response type but not it's methods?

The 'funny' fact is that in plain js everything works. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Here's my tsconfig.json file if it can help:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: the `res` is the response... and `end` exits the response... while you should use `res.send`, here's the documentation: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_response_object.htm

Comment: that's not the problem anyway D: neither send() or end() works. Both gets underlined in red. Thanks for taking the time to comment :)

Comment: have you done `var express = require("express");`?

Comment: i've tryied both `import * as express from 'express'` and `var express = require('express')` but nothing changed

Comment: you did install express using the commandline? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-express-a-node-js-framework-and-set-up-socket-io-on-a-vps here's how you install express

Comment: sure `npm i --save express`

Comment: you could take a look at the documentation I send, maybe you missed a step? plus `express.response` isn't a function

Comment: actually i've did it that way, and created the project with express-generator then cd into it and launched `npm i`

Comment: could you explain what you want to do with the responses? or what you want them to do? and I take you followed this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial ???

Comment: I'm just trying to write my project in Typescript instead of JavaScript. To have types checks. Just that, it's not a matter of Responses, Requests etc. It's just a problem that in js autocomplete works like a charm and in Ts it's not :)

Comment: interesting... but I don't think I could help you out on this one :( sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved by myself

For some reason now `import * as express from 'express'` now gives me the correct completition and type checking. However trying this before didn't worked. That's odd, however closing it as solved.